# Como alterar tamanho da borda de gráfico de barra no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um gráfico de barras no R feito com a função `geom_col`. Gostaria de diminuir o tamanho das bordas, porque não está mostrando o preenchimento do gráfico. Tentei utilizar o argumento `width`, mas está alterando só o tamanho do preenchimento e não resolveu o problema.

Como está saindo o gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou utilizando:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(zoo)
})

url <- httr::GET("https://xx9p7hp1p7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/PortalGeral",
                 httr::add_headers("X-Parse-Application-Id" =
                                     "unAFkcaNDeXajurGB7LChj8SgQYS2ptm")) %>%
  httr::content() %>%
  '[['("results") %>%
  '[['(1) %>%
  '[['("arquivo") %>%
  '[['("url")

dados <- utils::read.csv2(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1")
dados$data <- lubridate::as_date(dados$data)

dados <- dados %>%
  filter(data > as.Date("2020-02-29"))

rm(url)

dados %>%
  mutate(mm7dCasos = rollmean(casosNovos, 7, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA), align = "right")) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-03-14") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = casosNovos), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", fill = "white", width = 0.75) +
  geom_line(aes(x = data, y = mm7dCasos), colour = "#FF6347", size = 0.4) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  ggtitle("Variação diária de novos casos confirmados - Brasil", "(MM7d)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1000)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3)
```

Comment: Não foi possível encontrar a função "rollmean"

Comment: Perdão, o pacote estava pré carregado no meu R, já o inclui no código.

Comment: Já viu o resultado se remover `color` de `geom_col`?

Comment: Se eu remover o ```color```, o ```ggplot2``` só deixa sem a borda.

Comment: Tente mudar o argumento `size` no `geom_col`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para isso basta adicionar o argumento `size` na função `geom_col`. O argumento `width`altera o tamanho do preenchimento, enquanto o `size` altera o tamanho da borda.

Código novo:

```
dados %>%
  mutate(mm7dCasos = rollmean(casosNovos, 7, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA), align = "right")) %>%
  filter(data > "2020-03-14") %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = data, y = casosNovos), na.rm = TRUE, color = "black", fill = "white", size = 0.1, width = 0.75) +
  geom_line(aes(x = data, y = mm7dCasos), colour = "#FF6347", size = 0.4) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  ggtitle("Variação diária de novos casos confirmados - Brasil", "(MM7d)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 1000)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "2 week") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 10), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~estado, nrow = 3)
```